# VS Code Emmet - Not Using Tab

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use VS Code for coding typescript. Every time I press TAB to add an indent it replaces my code with tags. For example, while typing a word 'line1' after pressing TAB it's replacing it with "`<line1></line1>`".

How do I get rid of this behaviour?

I tried to add changes to my settings:

```
"emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "typescript"
] ,
"emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly"
```

But still are no changes.

Comment: check `"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab"` rule in your settings

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: mine and according to [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet) is false by default which is why my above question was for you to check if it is set

Comment: // When enabled, Emmet abbreviations are expanded when pressing TAB - in mys case it's not abbreviations it just replaces my TS code by HTML tags.